# Confusion of mx record and send mail from home server

Tags: email, mx-record

Is mx record means 
once anyone want to send the mail to others, they have to go to dns to register a one mx record , that is a domain name, such as hotmail .com, in this domain name will point to at least one address of the server.

So , it introduce reverse dns, which is , when I send the mail to the others, the other side will check whether the 'from' ip has a domain name in public dns , if the ip can not find any domain name related to it, the mail server will block the incoming message.

Is my concept correct? And what is A record and PTR do ?

Comment: Re: the last line of your question, `And what is A record and PTR do ?`, I ***STRONGLY*** suggest picking up a copy of [DNS and BIND](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100575.do) -- This question indicates a fundamental lack of understanding re: the concepts underlying DNS, which this book will help remedy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I send an e-mail to yourdomain.com, it checks for the MX-records of yourdomain.com to find which mailserver(s) handles this.

Your second paragraph is correct. Many enables the option to check the reverse lookup of the IP sending the e-mail.

Your concept is correct indeed!

A-record is a record pointing to the IP-address of a server. 
A typical record could look like: 
yourdomain.com     521     IN      A    192.168.1.1 (<- random IP)

When you run a ping against     yourdomain.com it will try the IP listed in the A-record.

PTR records are reverse lookup records.

I hope any of this makes sense!

Comment: To add: you are not supposed to send emails froma  home server, use a real server / your provider to rlay. Home servers are notoriously ONLY sending spam. Noone accepts email from dynamic address space.

Comment: then what is the difference of mx and a record?

Comment: MX is specific for mail-traffic.

Comment: is mx record is for email domain and a record is for webpage?

Comment: That's one way of putting it yes!

Comment: Glad I could help! :)